# Making multiple Segues iOS9

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios9

I have been at this for sometime now and all I can find is simple Segues via google. I will do my best to show you what I am trying to do and provide snapshots as to what I am doing.

[image]

The middle controller is a simple segue to the map. It will be the root. I created a new file "Cocoa Touch Class"

[image]

Now I created a IBOutlet to the "Cocoa Touch Class" I just created for the map.

[image]

Now I get an error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type  
NSException
```

[image]

Am I adding the controllers incorrectly? I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The root or "Home" will send the user to many different pages depending on what they press. From my understanding user each page will be its own view like I am trying to do above. However I feel I am doing something wrong, I am just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because in storyboard you have created UIViewController and attached it to UITableViewController. Try change Base class for your controller from UITableViewController to UIViewController.

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentlemen!

And I am blind :(